# Code won't compile and i don't understand what these errors are for

Tags: c#, syntax-error, console-application

so as the title says my code won't compile i get multiple issues now and before when it was formatted differently it worked to some extent. but now the code completly refuses to run and with my current level of understanding i am unable to figure out the issue but i believe the issue is just the way i've formatted the program so it follows the flowchart.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // SETUP SESSION
            // Declare variables
            Int32 currentGuess, upperLimit, randomNumber;
            double maxGuesses;
            char playAgain;
            Random random = new Random();


            // WELCOME THE USER
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the high/low guessing game.");

            //INITILIZE WIN COUNT AND GAME COUNT

            Int32 gameCount = 0, winCount = 0;

            //DO LOOP #1
            do
            //SETUP GAME
            {
            //REQUEST USER FOR UPPER LIMIT
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Upper range (e.g. 100):");
                upperLimit = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                //INITILIZE GUESS COUNT
                Int32 guessCount = 0;
                bool gameOver = false;

                //DETERMINE RANDOM NUMBER
                randomNumber = random.Next(1, upperLimit);
                //DETERMINE MAX GUESSES
                maxGuesses = Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(upperLimit, 2) - 1);

                // INFORM USER RANDOM NUMBER IS CHOSEN AND INDICATE NUMBER OF GUESSES ALLOWED 
                Console.WriteLine("I picked a number between 1 and {0} you get {1} chances to guess it", upperLimit, maxGuesses);

            //DO LOOP #2
            do
                            {
                                //PLAY GAME
                               //READ GUESSES
                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format(" Enter Guess {0}: ", guessCount));
                            currentGuess = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                            if (currentGuess == randomNumber)
                            {
                                //INCRIMENT WIN COUNT
                                winCount++;
                            }
                            if (currentGuess == randomNumber)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("You got it!");
                                gameOver = true;
                                gameCount++;
                            }
                            else if (currentGuess > randomNumber)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Too High");
                            }
                            else if (currentGuess < randomNumber)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Too Low");
                            }


                            } while (guessCount < maxGuesses &&  gameOver == false);

                //POST PROCESSING GAME

                             if (guessCount++ == maxGuesses)
                                        {
                                            //INCRIMENT GAME COUNT
                                            gameCount++;
                                            Console.WriteLine("You lost");
                                            //DISPLAY CORRECT NUMBER IF TOO MANY INCORRECT GUESSES
                                            Console.WriteLine("\nThe number was {0},better luck next time!", randomNumber);
                                            guessCount = 1;

                                 //PROMPT TO PLAY AGAIN

                                           Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? (Y/N)");
                                           playAgain = char.Parse (Console.ReadLine());


                                       }
                                           while (playAgain == 'y' ||playAgain == 'Y');

                          // display win count 
                         Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing, you won {0} out of {1} games", winCount, gameCount);
                         Console.ReadLine();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're getting an error message, post it. Please don't ask us to guess what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two errors in your program. First, before using a variable it must always be initialized. If you look at the different paths your `playAgain` variable can take, the value is only set in your `if (guessCount++ == maxGuesses)` path. If the condition is false, you'll get to the `while` part without any value. You can change the declaration to

```
char playAgain = 'n';
```

The second error was a missing bracket. If you carefully do the indentation, you will see this :

```
do
{
    //Bunch of code
    if (guessCount++ == maxGuesses)
    {
        //INCRIMENT GAME COUNT
        gameCount++;
        Console.WriteLine("You lost");
        //DISPLAY CORRECT NUMBER IF TOO MANY INCORRECT GUESSES
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe number was {0},better luck next time!", randomNumber);
        guessCount = 1;

        //PROMPT TO PLAY AGAIN

        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? (Y/N)");
        playAgain = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

} while (playAgain == 'y' || playAgain == 'Y');
```

as you can see, you're missing the `if` bracket, it should be

```
   playAgain = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   }

} while (playAgain == 'y' || playAgain == 'Y');
```

Also, there are a *LOT* of things you could improve. For example, you should place your variable declarations where they are used not at the top of the class. Each comment should be a separate method; it would be way easier for you to follow your flowchart if your Main, instead of being a huge blob of code was something like:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WelcomeTheUser();
    InitializeWinCountAndGameCount();
    Play();
    DisplayWinCount();
}
```

You could also avoid a ton of misplaced brackets if you keep your functions small.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. You are missing a squirly bracket before your last while in your outer do while loop.
2. You need to initialize the "playAgain" char when you declare it.

;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
            // SETUP SESSION
            // Declare variables
            Int32 currentGuess, upperLimit, randomNumber;
            double maxGuesses;
            char playAgain = 'n';
            Random random = new Random();

            // WELCOME THE USER
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the high/low guessing game.");

            //INITILIZE WIN COUNT AND GAME COUNT

            Int32 gameCount = 0, winCount = 0;

            //DO LOOP #1
            do
            //SETUP GAME
            {
                //REQUEST USER FOR UPPER LIMIT
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Upper range (e.g. 100):");
                upperLimit = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                //INITILIZE GUESS COUNT
                Int32 guessCount = 0;
                bool gameOver = false;

                //DETERMINE RANDOM NUMBER
                randomNumber = random.Next(1, upperLimit);
                //DETERMINE MAX GUESSES
                maxGuesses = Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(upperLimit, 2) - 1);

                // INFORM USER RANDOM NUMBER IS CHOSEN AND INDICATE NUMBER OF GUESSES ALLOWED 
                Console.WriteLine("I picked a number between 1 and {0} you get {1} chances to guess it", upperLimit, maxGuesses);

                //DO LOOP #2
                do
                {
                    //PLAY GAME
                    //READ GUESSES
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(" Enter Guess {0}: ", guessCount));
                    currentGuess = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (currentGuess == randomNumber)
                    {
                        //INCRIMENT WIN COUNT
                        winCount++;
                    }
                    if (currentGuess == randomNumber)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You got it!");
                        gameOver = true;
                        gameCount++;
                    }
                    else if (currentGuess > randomNumber)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Too High");
                    }
                    else if (currentGuess < randomNumber)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Too Low");
                    }


                } while (guessCount < maxGuesses && gameOver == false);

                //POST PROCESSING GAME

                if (guessCount++ == maxGuesses)
                {
                    //INCRIMENT GAME COUNT
                    gameCount++;
                    Console.WriteLine("You lost");
                    //DISPLAY CORRECT NUMBER IF TOO MANY INCORRECT GUESSES
                    Console.WriteLine("\nThe number was {0},better luck next time!", randomNumber);
                    guessCount = 1;

                    //PROMPT TO PLAY AGAIN

                    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? (Y/N)");
                    playAgain = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


                }
            } while (playAgain == 'y' || playAgain == 'Y');

            // display win count 
            Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing, you won {0} out of {1} games", winCount, gameCount);
            Console.ReadLine();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you i also found another issue in it where guess count wouldn't increment so i fixed it so now it works thanks for pointing it out i thought i had looked at all the brackets but guess not